# find intersections in set of lines that are bigger than sum of variables

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, coordinate-systems

I have

$$\begin{align}
x \cdot 5.16 &\geq x + z + y\\
z \cdot 5.48 &\geq x + z + y\\
y \cdot 6.36 &\geq x + z + y
\end{align}$$

and I'm trying to find what can $x, z,$ and $y$ be. For example: $x = 1, z = 1, y = 1$ will respect the constraint. But if I have

$$\begin{align}x \cdot 2.16 &\geq x + z + y\\
z \cdot 5.48 &\geq x + z + y\\
y \cdot 6.36 &\geq x + z + y\end{align}$$

the $(x = 1, z = 1, y = 1)$ would not respect the constraint.
In this case, I would like to know how to find the possible values of $(x, z, y)$ be. $(x,z,y)$ also need to be positive (excluding 0)

Comment: Are $x,y,z$. supposed to be positive?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ig yes otherise $x=y=z=0$ is a trivial solution

Comment: @abcdefu Well, zero. values aren't the only possibility other than positive.

Comment: There are infinite solutions to this, in fact

Comment: You have three planes through $(0,0,0)$ (replacing $\geq$ with $=$) and the inequalities select one of the octants that the planes divide space up into. I don't think there is a great way to specify these points outside of those three planes.

Comment: I suppose you can find three vectors that span that octants, so $v_1,v_2,v_3$ such that any element of that octant can be written $av_1+bv_2+cv_3$ where $a,b,c$ are non-negative reals.

Comment: One thing you can do is group the $x,y,z$ coefficients together and write it as a matrix equation $A(x,y,z) = (a,b,c)$ where $a,b,c \geq 0$, but I don't see an easily tractable way to obtain a closed form solution set.